# Matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ \space f:\mathbb{R^2} \mapsto \mathbb{R^3}$ be a linear transformation defined by $f(x,y)=(x+y,2x-y,x-y)$.

Let $A=\{(2,1),(1,1)\}$ and $B=\{(1,1,1),(1,2,1),(-1,0,-2)\}$ be basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R^3}$, respectively.

To find the matrix of $f$ I did it this way,

I calculated the images of $f$:

$f(2,1)=(3,3,1)$

$f(1,1)=(2,1,0)$

Now, each images have to be writen as a linear combination of $B$ basis.

$(3,3,1)=7\cdot(1,1,1)-2\cdot(1,2,1)+2\cdot(-1,0,-2)$

$(2,1,0)=7\cdot(1,1,1)-3\cdot(1,2,1)+2\cdot(-1,0,-2)$

So, the matrix that represents $f$, with respect of $A$ and $B$ is,

$$M=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}7&7\\-2&-3\\2&2\end{array}\right]$$

However if I multiply $M$ by $(2,1)$ I don't get $(3,3,1)$ as it was suppose.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}7&7\\-2&-3\\2&2\end{array}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{array}{cc}2\\1\end{array}\right]\neq\left[\begin{array}{cc}3\\3\\1\end{array}\right]$$

What is wrong?Thanks

Comment: I should add that there's nothing wrong except for the "as it was supposed to" part.

Comment: My mistake was to assume that the given vectors and its images are allready writen as a linear combination of the elements of the given basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that $(2,1)$ in this basis represents $2 (2,1) + 1(1,1)$ and not  the $(2,1)$ you originally worked with.

If you instead did $A \cdot (1,0)$, you would get $(7, -2, 2)$ which represents $(3,3,1)$

Comment: @João Do you understand this answer?

Comment: Now, I understant, the vector $(2,1)$ is not on the $A$ basis. I have to write it as a linear combination of $A$ and I'll get $(1,0)$.I had suppose that the vector $(2,1)$ was already in the $A$ basis,but it seems that was in the standard basis. Thanks.

Comment: @João There's something more missing. Do you see it? I mean missing from your reasoning, not from the answer.

Comment: No!I don't see what I missing

Comment: You write $(2,1)$ as a linear combination of the elements of $A$ and get the $(1,0)$. That's correct. Now you multiply the matrix by $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and get something which isn't $(3,3,1)$. But the last line in Muzz's answer explains that.

Comment: Oh that! The vector $(7,-2,2)$ is on the $B$ basis. In fact, this vector is the first column of $M$ matrix. In other words, the coordinates of this vector are the coeficients of the linear combination of $(3,3,1)$ in $B$ basis. I think is that.